# ¿Por qué mi for se repite infinitamente, si yo le puse limitante?

Tags: c, bucle-for

Por alguna razón que desconozco mi `for` es infinito y no para aunque yo le haya puesto una variable de limitante y no sé por qué ocurre o por qué sucede; además, he visto otros ejemplos de otras personas y son iguales al código que yo he hecho.
Además no puedo poner una limitante fija como `a=3` porque o sino perdería el propósito del `for` en mi código que es repetir las veces que el usuario le indique.

Dejo el aquí el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{

    int Li=7,H=1,C=12,O=16,Na=23,Mg=25,Al=27,Si=28,P=31,S=32,Cl=36,K=39,Ca=40,Cr=24,Mn=25;

    int o,m,mm,d,a,acum=0,acu=0,ac,u,e,z,num;

    char f[0];
    printf ("de cuantos elementos es tu ecuacion= ");
    scanf("%d",&d);
for(a=1;a<=d;a++)
{
    printf("pon un elemento= ");
    scanf("%s",&f);

    if (strcmp(f, "Li") == 0)
    {
        printf("el numero atomico de Li es %d \n",Li);
                
                    printf("por cual sub incedice quieres multiplicar \n");
                    scanf("%d",&m);
                    mm=Li*m;
                    acum+=mm;
                    printf("el resultado es= %d \n",mm);
    }
    else
    {
        if(strcmp(f, "H") == 0)
        {
            printf("el numero atomico de H es %d \n",H);
                    printf("por cual quieres multiplicar \n");
                    scanf("%d",&m);
                    mm=H*m;
                    acum+=mm;
                    printf("el resultado es= %d \n",mm);
                
            
             
        }
        else
        {
            if(strcmp(f, "C") == 0)
            {
            printf("el numero atomico de C es %d \n",C);
                    printf("por cual quieres multiplicar \n");
                    scanf("%d",&m);
                    mm=C*m;
                    acum+=mm;
                    printf("el resultado es= %d \n",mm);
            }
            else 
            {
                if(strcmp(f, "O") == 0)
                {
                    printf("el numero atomico de O es %d \n",O);
            
                    printf("por cual quieres multiplicar \n");
                    scanf("%d",&m);
                    mm=O*m;
                    acum+=mm;
                    printf("el resultado es= %d \n",mm);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(strcmp(f, "Cerrar") == 0)
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
    printf("la masa molar es= %d \n",acum); 
}
```

Comment: Crea un [example]. Deja un ejemplo de entrada, el resultado obtenido y el resultado esperado.

Comment: Por cierto, dale nombres más descriptivos a tus variables. De hecho, sería más conveniente que hagas un arreglo con los nombres de los elementos ordenado por su número atómico. Por ejemplo: `char *nombres[] = { "No existe ningún átomo sin protones", "Hidrógeno", "Helio", "Litio", ... }`. Entonces si quieres acceder al elemento de número atómico 1, usas `nombres[1]`.

Comment: No manejo C++, por lo que mi comentario debe "tomarse con pinzas", tu for está bien, lo que veo, es que declaras: **char f[0];** si,no estoy equivocado, es un array de char, de tamaño "0", para más "inri",  después invocas **scanf("%s",&f);**, que, si no me equivoco, toma la cadena que ingresa el usuario, y se la asigna al array de char... de tamaño cero.... más que un bucle infinito, creo que tu programa "crashea", si me equivoco en algo... golpeen sin piedad!!.

Comment: El código que comparte @zila117 no es C++ si no C.

Comment: me niego a leer un codigo donde el nombre de las variables son "a" "b" "f" "c" "l" "o" "m" ... mas que nada pro que no quiero quedarme ciego. Un saludo

Answer (score 6):

Tu error se puede reproducir con este sencillo código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char s[0];

    scanf("%d",&i);
    scanf("%s",&s);

    for (int index = 0; index != i; ++index)
        printf("Index %d != i %d\n", index, i);

    return 0;
}
```

He introducido `5` y `patatas fritas` y me ha producido [la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##RUxLCsIwEF1nTjFWKgmt0o2rWPeeQV2EpLUBTUuSgiCePU6jILN48756e9M6pbV1@j6bDg8hGjvuhiOAdREfyjou4AVsYVYC04PyGM7NVQKwoJXreVGaot5YIf9CICGIJdKPHnkuO9M9scVG/t5VS4NYVZkJYGzylKP2KdulyQnCiyvqb4cgj/ouzt7RFLxT2sOkIl3A3lsC@AA):

> ```
> Index 0 != i 1635017072
> Index 1 != i 1635017072
> Index 2 != i 1635017072
> Index 3 != i 1635017072
> Index 4 != i 1635017072
> Index 5 != i 1635017072
> Index 6 != i 1635017072
> Index 7 != i 1635017072
> Index 8 != i 1635017072
> Index 9 != i 1635017072
> …
> ```

Si te fijas, para `i` he introducido `5` pero está usando `1635017072` ¿De dónde sale ese valor?

---

`1635017072` en hexadecimal es `0x61746170`. `0x61` es el valor hexadecimal de la letra `a`, `0x74` es el valor hexadecimal de la letra `t` y `0x70` es el valor hexadecimal de la letra `p`, por lo que ese "*extraño*" número es el texto `"atap"` ¿te es familiar?:

> ```
> satirf satatap
>           ^^^^
> ```

Forma parte del texto introducido pero al revés. El motivo por el que está al revés es que se ha escrito un texto en un entero (nosotros leemos el texto de izquierda a derecha pero los números se guardan de derecha a izquierda: el último bit está a la izquierda y el primer bit a la derecha) pero ¿por qué se ha escrito en el entero? Porque `s` no tiene tamaño (`s[0]`, cero elementos) e `i` se pone a continuación. Así pues al escribir en `s` estás escribiendo en `i`.

¡Pero las variables no están en ese orden!

```
    …

    int i;
    char s[0];

    …
```

En realidad sí, las variables se *apilan* en cada declaración, así que al *apilar* `s` después de `i`, `s` estará antes de `i`. Si le damos la vuelta a las declaraciones [el código "*funciona*"](https://tio.run/##RUxLCsIwEF1nTjFWKgmt0o2rWPeeQV2EpLUBTUuSgiCePU6jILN48756e9M6pbV1@j6bDg8hGjvuhiOAdREfyjou4AVMD8pjODdXCWxxrARgQSvX86I0Rb2xQv6FQEIQS6QfPfJccKZ7YouN/L2rlkawqjITwNjkKUftU7ZLkxOEF1fU3w5BHvVdnL2jKXintIdJRbqAvbcE8AE) (nótese las comillas):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char s[0];
    int i;

    scanf("%d",&i);
    scanf("%s",&s);

    for (int index = 0; index != i; ++index)
        printf("Index %d != i %d\n", index, i);

    return 0;
}
```

En tu código probablemente querías hacer esto:

```
char f[100]; // Dale un tamaño al búfer de lectura!
printf ("de cuantos elementos es tu ecuacion= ");
scanf("%d",&d);
```

Comment: Es acojonante tu manera de explicar las cosas. He tenido profesores que no pusieron ni un 1% del interés que pones tú en que los demás aprendan. Mi más sincera enhorabuena, de verdad.